# Selectively copy rows from one sheet to a new table on a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a quote log for my entire company pulled from an access database. The data populates nicely into a sheet in Excel. One column has the initials of the person in charge of the job.

I'd like to pull all rows from this table that have my initials in it, and copy only these rows into a new table on a separate sheet. I think this is probably a VBA issue, I'm new to VBA and just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

I can go down row by row with an if statement but that creates massive gaps where my initials aren't present.

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried so far? But I'm guessing that a `For Each` statement would be the best route.

Comment: =IF(Sheet3!E36="BW",Sheet3!L36,"")

is all I've come up with, this just goes row for row and leaves big gaps where it doesn't find BW.

Comment: Do you have a constraint that specifically calls for  VBA/ a codebased solution?  This is easy to do as a user using Data > Filter?  And if you do need to accomplish that via VBA you could try Range(“Your_Defined_range″).AutoFilter

Comment: I don't! I'm just new to all this and thought that would be the way to go. I will check out data filters, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try This. It looks for your criteria in column "E" and then it copies the rows containing that criterion, in this case `"BW"`, to a destination range which in this code is `("Sheet2")`. Hope this helps.

```
Sub Copyrowcriteria()
    Dim target As Worksheet
    Set target = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If Cells(i, 5).Value = "BW" Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5)).Copy destination:=target.Range("A" & target.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```